# What is the correct way to write a find() statement in CakePHP given a simple select query with ORDER and LIMIT?

Tags: php, cakephp

How to write this query using the find statement in cakephp

```
$this->Form->query("Select id from forms order by id DESC LIMIT 1")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$this->Form->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Form.id'),
    'order' => 'Form.id DESC',
    'limit' => 1
));
```

Comment: well, i get the value as "Array"

Comment: Angeline,

You should a) read the documentation a little more and b) try a print_r ($variable); to see what's inside the array.

Comment: why did u mean this 'all' with limit 1? when thats what 'first' does?

Comment: find('all') and find('first') return different data structures.  Technically 'first' will also do the job.

Comment: @Alexander: Truthfully I haven't messed around with CakePHP for a while now (1.1) so I wasn't sure if 'first' had the LIMIT 1 implied or not. My original answer used it, but I figured it is better to be safe than sorry so I changed it to 'all' with the explicit limit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/view/73/Retrieving-Your-Data

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first response here, 
2 things I would like to mention
I assume you have a model called Form,Now Cakephp has its own FormHelper and sometimes there maybe a conflict of names, I got this error when I had created a FilesController in my project,
Also you will get an array back which will be of the form

```
$result['Form] => array(
                   [id] => 1
                   [name] => whatever)
```

and so on, you can easily use this to get whatever data you want.

Comment: you're missing a ' after ['Form

Answer (score 0):

While this should be find('first'), the real issue is probably even simpler. I can only assume the only reason for doing such a query is to get the last inserted id. In the same "run" as a save you can get the inserted id in the model property by the same name:

```
$this->ModelName->create($this->data);
if ($this->ModelName->save()) {
  $this->Session->setFlash('Saved it!');

  $id_of_new_row = $this->ModelName->id;
  $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view',$id_of_new_row));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979757/cakephp-query/980238#980238) said, but adding 'recursive' to the query:

```
$this->Form->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Form.id'), // just return the id, thank you
    'order' => 'Form.id DESC',    // sort the query result by id DESC
    'limit' => 1,                 // gimme the top id
    'recursive' => -1,            // don't scan associated models in the query
));
```

but I'd also use

```
$this->Form->find('first', array(
     'fields' => array('Form.id'),
     'order' => array('Form.id DESC'),
     'recursive' => -1,
     )
);
```

Which is not much shorter, but is more expressive of what you want.

And I'd suggest you take care, because there's a form helper already, and confusion could happen. On the other hand, you use the $form variable in views, generally, while this is controller code.